# How do I extract the top value from pandas.DataFrame.describe()?

Tags: pandas, describe

[In]

```
df.describe()
```

[Out]

```
count          48016
unique            40
top       volkswagen
freq           10185
Name: brand, dtype: object
```

Here's what I've tried

df.value_counts().iloc[0,0]

That returned an error. I think it's because it is returns series and not a dataframe in which case, I cannot extract the top value, only the value count.

I then tried searching for the df.describe() parameters, but couldn't work with anything there.

Even foolishly tried df.describe().top() and df.describe(top) hoping either would work.

I feel like I'm missing something trivial here. How can I extract the top value ('volkswagen') in df.describe()?

Comment: Are you looking for `df.describe().top`?

Comment: @timgeb That's it! I guess I should have tried it without the parenthesis. Please post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any series, you can access a value by label via the dot notation or the square brackets `__getitem__` notation.

In this case, it's simply `df.describe().top` or `df.describe()['top']`.